# Double integral

Tags: homework

I am trying to use mathematica to verify a math problem which is a double integral:
$$\int \int_D (3x+4)^4 \delta x\delta y$$
with $$0 \leq x \leq 4, 0 \leq y \leq 4,$$
I tried the following:

-drawing function:

```
f[x_, y_] := (3 x + 4 y)^4; R = ImplicitRegion[{0 < x < 4, 0 < y < 1}, {x, y}]; Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] R]
```

And then writing a double integral in mathematica with the escape hotkey.

```
\!\( \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(4\)]\( \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(1\)]f[x, 
    y] \[DifferentialD]y \[DifferentialD]x\)\)
```

I tried as well:

```
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, o, 1}]
```

The first attempt gives me output 32, and the second gives me output:

```
-(512/5) (-374 + 162 o + 135 o^2 + 60 o^3 + 15 o^4 + 2 o^5)
```

Can you please help?

Comment: You use `o` variable for `y` limits in second approach. That's the issue.

Comment: Shoot. Sorry about that. I changed the o to zero, but it does not give me a result still?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what `...writing a double integral in mathematica with the escape hotkey` means, but the three versions

```
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 1}]
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] R]
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(4\)]\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(1\)]f[x, y] \[DifferentialD]y \[DifferentialD]x\)\)
(*  191488/5 *)
```

give the same result!

Comment: It's when you press escape, and write int, and then escape again :)

Comment: Can you please write how to plot it? I tried Plot3D, Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y}]

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the click-version `basic math input`...

Comment: Dovendyr@ `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] R] `

Comment: I get error: Plot3D::idomdim: {x,y}\[Element]R does not have a valid dimension as a plotting domain.

Comment: My MMA version  11.0.1.0 (Windows 64-bit)  plots without error.

Comment: I only have a student version, but it does not seem like a reason for the bug :D

Comment: I'm missing the backslash "\" in your error message `{x,y}[Element]R ` , perhaps you forgot it in your plotcommand?

Answer (score 5):

An overkill for this particular problem, but the technique is useful for more complicated regions:

```
Integrate[
 f[x, y] Boole[0 < x < 4 && 0 < y < 1],
  {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> $\frac{191488}{5}$

---

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntegralsOverRegions.html
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html